# verify ssl certificate to authenticate the services accessing our private api?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, ssl, rack

We have a webservice and 3 internal clients accessing it.
They all are hosted on the same domain and we use a ssl certificate *.ourdomain.com for all of them.

So we got :

- https://ourapi.ourdomain.com
- https://1stclient.ourdomain.com
- https://2ndclient.ourdomain.com
- https://3rdclient.ourdomain.com

I was wondering if we could verify the identity of the requests (on the api) just by verifying the certificate. So we could trash basic authentication.

Do you think it's doable and secure ? How ? we're on rails 3.0.5 / ruby 1.9.2

Answer (score 1):

who's controlling your SSL termination in your environment ?
if you use EventMachine, you can use inside the post_init the

```
def post_init
    start_tls :private_key_file => 'mycert', :cert_chain_file => 'mychain', :verify_peer => true 
end
```

and then in the callback you can check the validity of the cert

```
  def ssl_verify_peer(cert)
    #TODO: check if the client cert is valid
  end
```

from a security point of view it is ok to check the validity of the client side ssl certificate. you just have to keep it secret. if someone steal that file, the auth will be bypassed. this is why it's a godd practice to use the cert + a pasword (two factor auth).

regards.